# Columnstore index - slow performance on offset-fetch query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, columnstore

We have Fact table around 35M rows on Azure database (premium tier), this table has cluster columnstore index enabled in order to boost query performance.

We did pagination (to index on Elastic Search) on Fact table using similar below code:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SPENDBY].[FactInvoiceDetail]
ORder by id
offset 1000000 rows fetch next 1000 rows only
```

But this query performs so slow, even over 10 minutes, it's not finished. If we change to use `TOP`, it works really well and take around 30 seconds:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [SPENDBY].[FactInvoiceDetail]
WHERE ID > 1000000 
ORDER BY Id
```

The estimated execution plan for offset-fetch query:

[image]

I am not sure that I understand whether `offset-fetch` query performs very poorly on cluster columnstore index or not.

This table also have a lot of none-cluster B-tree indexes on foreign keys and one unique index on the `Id` of Fact table in order to boost performance

This execution plan for offset-fetch query:

https://pastebin.com/BM8MXQMg

Comment: Can you share execution plans for both versions as XML

Comment: you also can paste the plan here :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: i also believe column store index  is great for aggregations against huge dataset,In this case, you are just returning all rows, a normal appropriate index woul suffice,but adding top is altering your plans

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Sorry I don't know how to generate the execution plans as XML, please could you show me

Comment: please see this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/save-an-execution-plan-in-xml-format

Comment: thanks, you meant the estimated execution plans?

Comment: No, Actual execution plans

Comment: I cannot paste the execution place on the website you sent, it's invalid, that's weird

Comment: That's not accurate,I assume you are talking about brentozar paste the plan.you also can paste in paste bin and update your question

Comment: sorry I don't understand the pastebin you mentioned, what does it mean? Btw, the offset-fetch seems run forever, that I cannot get the execution plan

Comment: Search for paste bin,you will get site where you can paste your plans and share the url

Comment: Thanks, the query is still running. I will update when it's done

Comment: OFFSET FETCH needs to use the PK to order the rows, but then is doing a lookup against the CCI for each row.  This is a very inefficient way to use a CCI.  If you need to page, you should probably have a BTree clustered index, and an nonclustered Columnstore for scanning.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: The query is executing for long time, so I have to cancel it.

Comment: @DavidBrowne: I do have unique non-cluster index on `Id`, does it not help?

Comment: @CuongLe:you are the only one who can answer,since we dont have any other info other than query running slow

Comment: @TheGameiswar: I have managed to get execution plan for offset-fetch, updated the answer

Comment: Whose idea was it to page through the fact?  I've heard about drill-down but this seems a bit ridiculous.  No human could consume 35 million records.  Refactor to allow drill-down via filters.  I'm also wondering if an index hint could help.

Comment: Your query is selecting rows, which is fine, but a columnstore is tuned to select, instead, aggregate values. If you wanted the SUM(), MIN, or something like that then the columnstore is a great choice. If all you want is rows, that's rowstore (a traditional table or index). If you don't call aggregates, columnstore can be a needless cost to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

```
1) Ordering BTree index is not a covering index for the paging query.

2) The rows must be reconstructed from the CCI.

3) The offset is large.
```

Paging queries need a BTree index on the ordering columns to calculate which rows should be returned, and if that BTree index doesn't include all the requested columns, then a row lookup be required for each row.  This is the "Nested Loops" operator in the query plan.

But the rows are stored in a CCI which means that each column is in a separate data structure, and reading a single row requires one Logical IO for each column, for each row.  That's why this query is especially expensive.  And why a CCI is a poor choice for a paging query.  A Clustered Index on the ordering columns, or a non-clustered index on the ordering columns with the remaining requested columns included would be much better.

A secondary and smaller issue here is the large offset.  SQL has to skip over the offset rows, counting them at it goes.  So this will reading the first N pages of the BTree leaf level pages to skip over rows.

Comment: It does make sense, for the item 1, I do have the Non-cluster B-Tree index on Id, but it seems not help much?

Comment: that is answered as well(offset is large)

Comment: " I do have the Non-cluster B-Tree index on Id" But it does not include all the columns requested in the query.  The BTree is being used to calculate which rows to return, but those rows aren't on the BTree.  They have to be fetched one-by-one from the CCI.

Answer (score 2):

this statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [SPENDBY].[FactInvoiceDetail]
WHERE ID > 1000000 
ORDER BY Id
```

works entirely with the (clustered?) ID field index (is primary key?) having ID > 1000000 ready

the other statement sorts and SEARCHES for the ID value that will fulfill the offset 1000000 rows

the offset 1000000 rows is not equal to WHERE ID > 1000000 for the optimizer unless there are no gaps to the ID values.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is with OFFSET large value..

> offset 1000000 rows fetch next 1000 rows only

OFFSet and Fetch works great,when the OFFSET value is small,see below example for more details

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, filler
FROM dbo.Orders
ORDER BY orderdate DESC, orderid DESC
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I have the order by columns as key columns and columns in select are included..this results in below plan..

key point to observe here is SQLServer ends up reading Offset+fetch (50+10 ) rows and then finally filtering 10 rows

[image]

So with your large Offset, you will be ending with 1000000+1000 row reads even with a suitable index,which is very huge

If you can ask ,sql server to filter out 1000 rows immediately after scan,that can help your query..this **may be**(not tested for your schema)  achieved by rewriting your query like below

```
WITH CLKeys AS
(
 SELECT ID
 FROM yourtable
 ORDER BY ID desc
OFFSET 500000 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT K.*, O.rest of columns 
FROM CLKeys AS K
CROSS APPLY (SELECT columns needed other than id
FROM yourtable  AS A
WHERE A.id= K.id) AS O
ORDER BY Id desc;
```

**References:**
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/offsetfetch-part-1#comment-25061

Comment: Thanks, so columnstore index is the main reason to slow down performance or because the fact table has really big data?

Comment: As explained,the column store index is of not much use for the query you have,you also can create a seperate index with id as unique index,just to satisfy the query(this filters only 1000 rows) and rest of the query can use keylookup to get remaining columns

Comment: What I don't get is why SQL Server can't figure out that it doesn't need to read that 500000 rows.  You're making it explicit in the CTE SQL, but SQL Server should know that it has a nonclustered index that contains the `ORDER BY` field(s), and therefore be able to execute the OFFSET part of the query with that index alone - there should only be a need for 10 actual readings of the table data to get the rest of the columns.

Comment: I read some where like, they try to make small improvements to query optimizer in each version of sql server,hopefully,this will be fixed .@Jez

Comment: Your query is selecting rows, which is fine, but a columnstore is tuned to select, instead, aggregate values. If you wanted the SUM(), MIN, or something like that then the columnstore is a great choice. If all you want is rows, that's rowstore (a traditional table or index). If you don't call aggregates, columnstore can be a needless cost to you.